# Yandex maps. Как получить геокоординаты всех почтовых отделений в конкретном городе(Москва)?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

Пробовал различными способами, один из которых:
"Формат запроса. API поиска по организациям"
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosearch/doc/concepts/request.html
На максимальное кол-во отделений стоит органичение, result = 500
Но как быть, если мне нужно получить все отделения, которые есть в конкретном городе?
**Мне это нужно, чтобы на собственной карте отобразить все точки почтовых отделений города Москвы**, буду безумно благодарен за помощь. Изучил почти всю документацию yandex maps api, но решения задачи не нашел.
Так же пробовал "multi-geocoder", устанавливал npm пакет, но в консоли ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at init.
Вот код:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.74, 37.58],
        zoom: 13,
        controls: []
    });
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search'
        }
    });
    
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

    var MultiGeocoder = require('multi-geocoder'),
    geocoder = new MultiGeocoder({ coordorder: 'latlong', lang: 'ru-RU' });

geocoder.geocode([
    'Москва, 1905 года ул., д.19',
    'Москва, 1-ая Квесисская ул., д 18',
    'Москва, 1-й Тверской-Ямской пер, д.16'
    ], {
    lang: 'en-US'
})
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: https://dadata.ru/api/suggest/postal_unit/

Comment: Дело в том, что и это пробовал). Выдает не все отделения, около 10 отделений почты при поиске в Москве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яндекс не позволяет выгружать свои данные – это нарушает [пользовательское соглашение](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/). Поэтому и методов таких не предоставляет.

Если был бы нужен виджет доставки Почты России, вам следовало обратиться в поддержку самой ПР, но могут ли они для вашей личной карты выдать такую информацию, сомневаюсь.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.